# Skip to else if property is undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I have function that creates a team and puts data to database. Now I'm trying to check if team already exists, if it does exists then reply with message. I have problem with my if statement.

> if (result[0].teamname == teamName)

When result[0].teamname is undefined it shows Cannot read property 'teamname' of undefined it ignores else and throws an error. How can I make so that does not ignore else?

Here is the function I use to create team.

```
function createTeam(teamName, members, message) {
teamName = teamName.replace("_", " ");
let insertTeam = `INSERT INTO teams (teamname) VALUES ('${teamName}');`;

db.select(`SELECT id_t, teamname FROM teams WHERE teamname = '${teamName}'`, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        if (result[0].teamname == teamName) {
            if (message.guild !== null) message.delete();

            message.reply("this team already exists!");
        } else {
            db.query(insertTeam);

            db.select(`SELECT id_t FROM teams WHERE teamname = '${teamName}'`, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) db.query(`INSERT INTO team_user (user, team) VALUES ('${members[i]}' , ${result[0].id_t})`);
                }
            });

            if (message.guild !== null) message.delete();

            let newTeam = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/542789472421675028.png?v=1")
            .setColor("#15f153")
            .addField("New team has been created!", `Team ${teamName} has been created with total of ${members.length} members!\nGood luck!`);

            message.channel.send(newTeam);
        }
    }
});
```

What have I tried so far:

1. Checking if result[0].teamname is undefined
2. Checking if result length is not 0
3. try-catch statement

Comment: Does your result object have a property with the row count? I don't think you really need to check the team name from the results, you're already querying by team name. You just need to check if the number of rows returned from the result is >= 1

Comment: `if(result && result[0] && result[0].teamname && result[0].teamname == teamName)` should do it. It short-circuits if any condition comes back false (instead of continuing on and looking for the `teamname` property of a possibly nonexistent object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if (result[0] && result[0].teamname == teamName)

First of all you need to check if result[0] is not undefined

Comment: Try your code with `result = undefined` ;)
I'm sure you forgot to check for result too

Comment: Oh, welp... I feel stupid now. Helped, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) the condition. All this means is you want to first check that `result` exists before checking properties of `result`

So for example, your code should look like this:

```
if (result && result[0] && result[0].teamname == teamName) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If result is array with more then one value, then you need to iterate over every one of them, you can use filter array method for this:

```
var found = result.filter((row) => row.teamname == teamName);

if (found.length) {

}
```

You can also as @ThomasKleßen mention in comment check if result is not undefined:

```
var found = result && result.filter((row) => row.teamname == teamName).length;

if (found) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a default value

```
if ((result || [{}])[0].teamname == teamName)
```

If the result is falsy, it will default to an array of an empty object, which will allow for the array access and dot notation to work, but the equality to fail.